# What is a trackable object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm browsing the documentation around `SavedModels`, and `tf.saved_model.save` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save)) does:

> Exports the Trackable object obj to SavedModel format.

**What is a trackable object**, I have not been able to find anything regarding this. Except for my PyCharm debugger printing it.

---

I am reading the documentation because I need to understand how SavedModels work. I've tried to load some SavedModels and subsequently convert these to TensorFlow lite/ coreML. Things are not going well in this respect, and I'm completely lost there so I won't bother mentioning it much detail in this question.

Comment: `Trackable` shows up 2813 times in the `tensorflow/tensorflow` repo, do we know what it is? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same question and I looked for the answer. Here is the answer. Directly quoting from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint?hl=es-419#used-in-the-notebooks_1):

TensorFlow objects may contain trackable state, such as [**tf.Variables**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable?hl=es-419), [**tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer?hl=es-419) implementations, **[tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=es-419)** iterators, `tf.keras.Layer` implementations, or **[tf.keras.Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=es-419)** implementations. These are called **trackable objects**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, I am still trying to understand what the significance/concept is.  This answer is a bit like saying that `sin(x)`, polynomials in x, and `log(x)` are differentiable in `x` without defining what "differentiable functions" are.  When we say an object is trackable, what can we do with it?  Thanks!